# How to import login ip ranges in salesforce using data loader?

Tags: data-loader

Can someone let us know how to import login ip ranges in salesforce using data loader?

Thanks,
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

The login IP ranges are part of metadata and not data, hence cannot be imported by data loader which is used for data migration. To deploy login IP ranges by metadata api, deploy the corresponding part of profile.

```
<loginIpRanges>
    <endAddress>255.255.255.255</endAddress>
    <startAddress>0.0.0.0</startAddress>
</loginIpRanges>
```

The above snippet is a part of the profile metadata. Migrating this in the profile to the target org will add this IP ranges to trusted IP ranges for the given profile in the target org. Hope this helps.
Also please see a previous entry regarding the same in SFSE - [Is there any way to deploy login IP ranges for the profiles?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/78762/is-there-any-way-to-deploy-login-ip-ranges-for-the-profiles)

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the reply. By searching over a web, I found that there would be a object named as LoginIpRanges in salesforce through which we can import IP ranges for profiles by means of data loader. But, we are not able to see this object in data loader. Is it something that have been deprecated by salesforce?

Comment: @PankajGanwani There is no standard object called 'LoginInRanges'. But there is a standard object named 'LoginIp'. Please see - https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_loginip.htm . But this object does not support create() call hence again don't think it is possible to create records of this object by data loader. Thanks